# Java spring REST controller: incomplete request body

Tags: java, spring, rest, hana, sap-cloud-platform

I have a problem with my REST Controller. If I sent a request with a RequestBody (json) some attributes doesn't arrive the controller, although they was sent and defined at model.

I could find out that it look like an old version of files will be used from the local java web server. As I changed the System.out.println Value at Constructor still the old value was outputed.

```
public RestController_ApiKey_2_0() {
    System.out.println("RestController_ApiKey_2_0 init");
}
```

I tried the following things bootless:

1. deleted java web server and did a new installation
2. cleaned the project and started server again
3. clean install of project

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Make sure your JSON is valid for deserialization.

Comment: The JSON is not the problem. Other attributes from that json object works without problems.

Comment: That doesn't mean all attributes will works. Suppose your JSON have two objects A and B, but B in your code is not Serializable, it will fail. I've experienced multiple serialization/deserialization problems when dealing with complex data-structure. I'm not sure what your are trying to achieve due to lack of details, but keep in mind that it is possible. If the JSON (as string) is properly filled with all datas and that when sent, in your controller, the received object miss fields, then it is most likely a deserialization issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more code, how do you declare a controller, and what params it can take. Also show a sample request. 
Here is an example of a simple controller:

A model

```
public class CustomRequestBody {
    private String fieldA;
    private String fieldB;

    public String getFieldA() {
        return fieldA;
    }

    public void setFieldA(final String fieldA) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }

    public String getFieldB() {
        return fieldB;
    }

    public void setFieldB(final String fieldB) {
        this.fieldB = fieldB;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/some-path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public ResponseEntity handleSomePath(@RequestBody final CustomRequestBody body, final HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Do the job.
    }
```

And request will be:

```
HTTP POST http://some.server.com/some-path
{
    "fieldA":"first value",
    "fieldB":"second value"
}
```

Read more at Spring documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller)